# A dialog's position changed after closing a QMessageBox in PyQt

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I wrote a `QMainWindow`, two `QDialog`, and one `QMessageBox`. The code is as follows:

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton, QMessageBox, QApplication, QAction, QMainWindow


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        action = QAction("Open DocumentDialog", self)
        action.triggered.connect(self.show_main_dialog)

        menu_bar = self.menuBar()
        file = menu_bar.addMenu("File")

        file.addAction(action)
        self.setWindowTitle("MainWindow")

    def show_main_dialog(self):
        main_dialog = DocumentDialog(self)
        main_dialog.show()


class DocumentDialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        btn = QPushButton("Open DocumentDetailDialog")
        btn.clicked.connect(self.btn_clicked)
        vbox.addWidget(btn)
        self.setLayout(vbox)
        self.setWindowTitle("DocumentDialog")

    def btn_clicked(self):
        detail_dialog = DetailDialog(self)
        detail_dialog.show()


class DetailDialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent: QDialog):
        super().__init__(parent)

        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        btn = QPushButton("Open delete message box")
        btn.clicked.connect(self.btn_clicked)
        vbox.addWidget(btn)
        self.setLayout(vbox)
        self.setWindowTitle("DetailDialog")

    def btn_clicked(self):
        msg_box = QMessageBox(self)
        msg_box.setIcon(QMessageBox.Warning)
        msg_box.setText("Are you sure?")
        msg_box.setWindowTitle("Delete")
        msg_box.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Ok | QMessageBox.Cancel)
        msg_box.buttonClicked.connect(self.delete_handler)
        msg_box.show()

    def delete_handler(self, btn):
        self.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

The process is as follows:

1. Start the app, then `MainWindow` shows itself.
2. Click on the menu item to show `DocumentDialog`.
3. Click on the button on `DocumentDialog` to show `DetailDialog`.
4. Click on the button on `DetailDialog` to show a `QMessageBox`.
5. Click on the button on `QMessageBox` to close it along with `DetailDialog`.

The `QMessageBox` is closed, as expected. the weird thing is, `DocumentDialog` is **over** `MainWindow` when it shows up. But after `QMessageBox` is closed, `DocumentDialog` hides **behind** `MainWindow`, why? How not to let `DocumentDialog` change it position?

I record a GIF to illustrate the process:

[image]

Comment: `show()` doesn't ensure that the dialog becomes (as in *behaves as*) modal. Try to use `detail_dialog.exec()` or eventually `detail_dialog.open()` instead.

Comment: You can try making it modal by `main_dialog.setModal(True)` (and probably `detail_dialog` as well).

Comment: @tromgy that's exactly what [`exec()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html#exec) and [`open()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html#open) do (I wrongly referenced `detail_dialog` in my comment, and didn't see the failed edit).

Comment: you should set the `pop up` flag **true** for your dialog this makes it always on top of your window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set `Qt.Popup` Flag for your Dialog :

This makes your Dialog always on top of others.

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton, QMessageBox, QApplication, QAction, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        action = QAction("Open DocumentDialog", self)
        action.triggered.connect(self.show_main_dialog)

        menu_bar = self.menuBar()
        file = menu_bar.addMenu("File")

        file.addAction(action)
        self.setWindowTitle("MainWindow")


    def show_main_dialog(self):
        main_dialog = DocumentDialog(self)
        main_dialog.show()


class DocumentDialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        btn = QPushButton("Open DocumentDetailDialog")
        btn.clicked.connect(self.btn_clicked)
        vbox.addWidget(btn)
        self.setLayout(vbox)
        self.setWindowTitle("DocumentDialog")

    def btn_clicked(self):
        detail_dialog = DetailDialog(self)
        detail_dialog.show()


class DetailDialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent: QDialog):
        super().__init__(parent)

        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        btn = QPushButton("Open delete message box")
        btn.clicked.connect(self.btn_clicked)
        vbox.addWidget(btn)
        self.setLayout(vbox)
        self.setWindowTitle("DetailDialog")
        self.setWindowFlags(self.windowFlags() |Qt.Popup)


    def btn_clicked(self):
        msg_box = QMessageBox(self)
        msg_box.setIcon(QMessageBox.Warning)
        msg_box.setText("Are you sure?")
        msg_box.setWindowTitle("Delete")
        msg_box.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Ok | QMessageBox.Cancel)
        msg_box.buttonClicked.connect(self.delete_handler)
        msg_box.show()

    def delete_handler(self, btn):
        self.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Result:

[image]

**Edited:**

From [Dialog modal](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html#modal-prop)

> This property holds whether show() should pop up the dialog as modal
> or modeless
>
> By default, this property is false and show() pops up the dialog as
> modeless. Setting this property to true is equivalent to setting
> QWidget::windowModality to Qt::ApplicationModal.
>
> exec() ignores the value of this property and always pops up the
> dialog as modal.

Then as @musicamante said you should change `show` to `exec` :

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        action = QAction("Open DocumentDialog", self)
        action.triggered.connect(self.show_main_dialog)

        menu_bar = self.menuBar()
        file = menu_bar.addMenu("File")

        file.addAction(action)
        self.setWindowTitle("MainWindow")


    def show_main_dialog(self):
        main_dialog = DocumentDialog(self)
        main_dialog.exec()


class DocumentDialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        btn = QPushButton("Open DocumentDetailDialog")
        btn.clicked.connect(self.btn_clicked)
        vbox.addWidget(btn)
        self.setLayout(vbox)
        self.setWindowTitle("DocumentDialog")

    def btn_clicked(self):
        detail_dialog = DetailDialog(self)
        detail_dialog.exec()


class DetailDialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent: QDialog):
        super().__init__(parent)

        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        btn = QPushButton("Open delete message box")
        btn.clicked.connect(self.btn_clicked)
        vbox.addWidget(btn)
        self.setLayout(vbox)
        self.setWindowTitle("DetailDialog")


    def btn_clicked(self):
        msg_box = QMessageBox(self)
        msg_box.setIcon(QMessageBox.Warning)
        msg_box.setText("Are you sure?")
        msg_box.setWindowTitle("Delete")
        msg_box.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Ok | QMessageBox.Cancel)
        msg_box.buttonClicked.connect(self.delete_handler)
        msg_box.exec()

    def delete_handler(self, btn):
        self.close()
```

Comment: That `Popup` description is based on the [`QML:Popup`](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-popup.html) type, which isn't related (at least, not directly) to the `Qt.Popup` window flag used for QWidgets. While they share common aspects, reference and context are wrong: the `Qt.Popup` flag is mostly used for popup menus, *not* modal windows. While this might work for macOS, it could be inappropriate for other systems (the fact that the OP shows macOS screenshots is irrelevant, as the question has no explicit relation to that OS). The proper solution is to use the `windowModality` property.

Comment: Note: the `windowModality` is always `Qt.NonModal` even for QDialogs created with a parent, only `QDialog.exec()` and `QDialog.open()` override that property to `Qt.WindowModal`. The `Qt.Popup` flag changes the window behavior depending on the system, so it **might** make it modal on certain systems, but there's no guarantee of that, and the behavior might change on the underlying window system and even along with different OS versions. Most importantly, that flag might not be enough to block user events (including focus) on other windows, which is the exact purpose of window modality.

Comment: @musicamante, I use ubuntu and it works well in my OS.

Comment: It works in the sense of "top level window" as long as it's just intended as "the window that is *first* shown above others". But that's not what window modality is: if you open the first dialog, you can still interact with the main window and open *another* dialog that will exist along with the previous one, and the same happens for the second dialog too. This is **not** what should happen for dialogs, as they are intended to be modal, meaning that they shall prevent any interaction with other windows until they are closed. Besides, the documentation reference to that flag is wrong anyway.

Comment: @musicamante, you mean I should delete my answer? I didn't understand, this works well but it's not the correct way? Now I test and see it, he `show` dialogs, and he should change them to `exec`.

Comment: No, you shouldn't delete it, but you can certainly improve it. As said, it works for the specific purpose of keeping the window stack order, but it doesn't properly prevent user interaction with previous dialogs (which wasn't explicit by the OP, but is the accepted convention for dialogs): I'd suggest you to expand your answer and explain what said above, warning both the OP and any future reader about the differences between setting the `Qt.Popup` flag and actually making the window modal with `exec()` or `open()`. While comments might suffice, the answer should be as complete as possible.

Comment: I don't want the dialog to be modal, I don't want the dialog to always be at the front, either. I just want these dialogs to keep their relative positions as long as the user doesn't change them. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: @Searene, From my experience of `QT` in `C ++ `and `Python`, **Dialogs** should be `exec` and **widgets** should be `show`. This is the first way that fixes what happens to you. the second choice is that use flags like `Qt. Popup`. Now, in these ways, your bug will be fixed and these dialogs will keep their relative positions as long as the user doesn't change them.